# How can i extract HTML code from secure URLs (https://)?

Tags: javascript, java, jsoup

I used JSoup library im not getting full html content from secure URLs (https://)
as the URL will get the  content dynamically. Is there any way to get the exact HTML content of secured URLs(https://).

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse the complete content you can use Selenium along with Jsoup.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com/");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
```

Or you can also wait for specific content to load.Shown below:

```
public void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
                }
            };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```